# Using JavaScript to populate text in div, but animation applies only to first text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a landing page where a series of texts are displayed on the screen and rotated through continuously. In addition, these texts need to be animated with a typewriter-like effect. I have the animation for the text working, but it only applies to the first text. When cycling through the rest of the texts, they are just shown on the page. Any idea how to fix this issue? I was thinking trying to add the animation CSS with JavaScript for every single text refresh, but this seems cumbersome and not the most efficient way.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // array with texts to type in typewriter
  var dataText = ["Hi, I'm Ned.", "Developer.", "Writer."];

  function typeWriter(i) {
    // add next text to h1
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = dataText[i] + '<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';

    // wait for a while and call this function again for next text
    setTimeout(function() {
      typeWriter((i + 1) % 3)
    }, 10000);
  }

  // start the text animation
  typeWriter(0);
});
```

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*Hide content before animation*/
  border-right: .1em solid white;
  /*Cursor*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*Keep text on same line*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*Scrolling effect while typing*/
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  animation: typing 3s steps(30, end), blink-caret .75s steps(1, end) infinite alternate;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
  <div class="typewriter">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that once the CSS animation is finished it wont be triggered again for that element. The only ways you can achieve a repeat is by either removing a css class (with the animation) from that element, **wait for a bit** and then readd it, or to destroy that element and re-create it.

For your example, I would simply create a new `h1`-element, edit its content and add that to the DOM. (And obviously removing the old one) Using jQuery, you can easily do that with

```
var h = $("<h1>");           //creating the element
h.innerHTML = ...;
$(".typewriter").empty();    //remove all children
$(".typewriter").append(h);  //add new h1 element
```

Plain JS Method:

```
var h = document.createElement("h1"); //creating the element
h.innerHTML = ...;          //setting its content
var typewriter = document.querySelector(".typewriter");
typewriter.innerHTML = '';  //remove all children
typewriter.appendChild(h);  //add the new h1 element
```

---

Also note that the way you have selected your query selector, these changes will apply to ALL `<h1>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could achieve what you want. Check it out:

```js
var dataText = [ "Hi, I'm Ned.", "Developer.", "Writer."];
 
    function typeWriter(i) {
        // add next character to h1
        
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.innerHTML = dataText[i] +'<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        document.querySelector(".typewriter").append(h1);
        

        // wait for a while and call this function again for next character
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector(".typewriter").innerHTML = ''; // add if(i === 2) to display the whole phrase
            typeWriter((i + 1)%3)
        }, 10000);
    }

    // start the text animation
    typeWriter(0);
```

```css
.typewriter h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: orange; 
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    font-size: 7em;
    overflow: hidden; /*Hide content before animation*/
    border-right: .1em solid white; /*Cursor*/
    white-space: nowrap; /*Keep text on same line*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Scrolling effect while typing*/
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    animation:
        typing 3s steps(30, end),
        blink-caret .75s steps(1, end) infinite alternate;
}
/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
   from { 
       width: 0
   }
   to { 
       width: 100% 
   }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
   from, to { 
       border-color: transparent 
   } 50% { 
       border-color: white; 
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
    <div class="typewriter">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
```

The trick is to make css animation work again. To do that, every time I create a new `h1` element. Once a part/the whole phrase is displayed I just remove all `h1` elements and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to make it easier, I added also a function to stop animation when your data is completely displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var dataText = [ "Hi, I'm Ned.", "Developer.", "Writer."];
function typeWriter(i) {
 var content = '<h1>' + dataText[i] +'<span aria-hidden="true"></span></h1>'
 $(".typewriter").append(content);
 // wait for a while and call this function again for next character
 var myFunc = setTimeout(function() {
  typeWriter((i + 1)%3)
  }, 10000);
  if (i  == dataText.length - 1) {
   clearTimeout(myFunc);
  }
    }

  // start the text animation
  typeWriter(0);
})
</script>


<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
    <div class="typewriter">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check it there : https://jsfiddle.net/z4cryxx0/2/

Let me know if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the animation as infinite and change the length of the animation to the delay you want between the change in the text, and then set it to finish after 3 seconds (which is at 30% here) or however long you want a single animation to last:

```
.typewriter h1 {
    ...
    animation:
        typing 10s steps(30, end) infinite,
        blink-caret .75s steps(1, end) infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes typing {
   0% {
     width: 0;
   }
   30% {
     width: 100%;
   }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that if you want to change the length of the delay between the texts, you have to modify both the JavaScript delay and the CSS animation length.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8fn3ywc/)